# Parse 'This query has an outstanding network connection'

Tags: ios, objective-c, parse-platform, fetch, pfquery

I have this error popping up in my app and causing a crash.

> This query has an outstanding network connection. You have to wait until it's done.

This comes when I am checking for a network connection and then querying Parse appropriately via local database or online.

You can see in my code below, I call `fetchPrivateRecordsForType` which create a `PFQuery` with data I pass in, such as a sort descriptor and predicate.

From this method I then call `testInternetConnection` which returns whether the device has a network connection. If it doesn't I tell the query to fetch `fromLocalDatastore`, else fetch from online.

I'll load up my app, fetch data from online, then toggle Airplane mode and fetch again, but the query go bananas and tells me there is no network and subsequently the final crash statement seen above.

I added in a BOOL check with `isTestingConnection` to even make sure the query isn't performed until there is confirmation whether we are connected or not, but it doesn't seem to have helped.

```
-(void)testInternetConnection:(void(^)(BOOL isConnected))complete
{
    _isTestingConnection = YES;
    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;

    internetReachableFoo = [Reachability reachabilityWithHostname:@"www.google.com"];

    // Internet is not reachable
    internetReachableFoo.unreachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Someone broke the internet :(");
            weakSelf.isTestingConnection = NO;
            complete(NO);
        });
    };

    // Internet is reachable
    internetReachableFoo.reachableBlock = ^(Reachability*reach)
    {
        // Update the UI on the main thread
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            NSLog(@"Yayyy, we have the interwebs!");
            weakSelf.isTestingConnection = NO;
            complete(YES);
        });
    };

    [internetReachableFoo startNotifier];
}

#pragma mark - Fetching

-(void)fetchPrivateRecordsForType:(NSString *)recordType predicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate sortDescriptor:(NSArray *)sortDescriptors includeKeys:(NSArray *)includeKeys page:(NSInteger)skipMultiplier complete:(void(^)(NSError *error, BOOL didFetchSuccessfully, NSArray *results))completeBlock
{
    PFQuery *query = nil;
    if (!predicate) query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:recordType];

    //PREDICATE
    else query = [PFQuery queryWithClassName:recordType predicate:predicate];

    //INCLUDE KEYS
    if (includeKeys) for (NSString *key in includeKeys) [query includeKey:key];

    //SORT DESCRIPTORS
    if (sortDescriptors && sortDescriptors.count > 0) [query orderBySortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    NSInteger limit = [self queryLimit];
    query.limit = limit;
    query.skip = (limit * skipMultiplier); //starts on page zero

    //fetch locally if no network connection
    [self testInternetConnection:^(BOOL isConnected) {
        if (!isConnected)
        {
            [query fromLocalDatastore];
        }

        NSLog(@"querying");
        if (!_isTestingConnection)
        {
            [query findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSArray *objects, NSError *error) {
                if (!error)
                {
                    //SUCCESS
                    completeBlock(error, YES, objects);
                }
                else
                {
                    //ERROR
                    //error handling should be done where this method is called
                    //this allows for me accurate and infomational errors, not a generic one from here
                }
            }];
        }
    }];
}

-(NSInteger)queryLimit
{
    return 100;
}
```

Some extra detail, just before the final crash hits with the `outstanding network connection` error, I get this error logged for no connection:

```
[Error]: Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1003 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found." UserInfo=0x1700fd380 {NSUnderlyingError=0x170243300 "A server with the specified hostname could not be found.", NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://api.parse.com/2/find, _kCFStreamErrorDomainKey=12, _kCFStreamErrorCodeKey=8, NSLocalizedDescription=A server with the specified hostname could not be found.} (Code: 100, Version: 1.6.1)
```

It seems this error is occurring because the query is performing with no connection, but I have made sure the query doesn't perform until we have confirmed an offline or online connection, and if it is offline I set to fetch from the local datastore. So this is another mystery to me...

**EDIT:**

A little extra info. Weirdly when I do this on iPhone, I have no issues. I can disconnect from the network and immediately perform a fetch and it will query the local database.

However, on iPad, if I query immediately after disconnecting from the network and don't give it 5-10 seconds to realise its disconnected, it will still think it is connected and throw this error and crash.

This makes me think it could be the reachability code, perhaps? Its the highly used Apple Reachability class (Tony Million's version).

Comment: Given that `fetchPrivateRecordsForType` is only getting 1 page of data, how often do you call it for a normal "fetch" from the UI, and do you wait for  the `findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock` to finish before you do things like turn on airplane mode?

Comment: Having scoured over my code many times, I'm certain the query only performs once. Also, if I `NSLog` when the query performs, it shows in the console as only be called once. As for the completion block, I do wait for that to call and the query to finish before disconnecting from the network, make no difference.